# Alternatives to "//" comments in eclipse.

Tags: java, eclipse, comments

What are these called in eclipse. They are blue by default. 
They are usually descriptive about what the class/method does and has an astrix in front of each line.

What is the keyboard shortcut to make these.

I've been using "//" comments and they are booty.

Time to upgrade.

Thanks.

```
/**
     * Returns a Button with save icon and proper styling applied.
     * Also adds a keyboard shortcut for Enter key.
     */
    public static final Button createSaveButton() { return createSubmitButton("Save");  }
```

Comment: That's a [Javadoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are called Javadoc comments. You don't need a shortcut for it. Just type `/**`  above the class/method and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Eclipse will automatically create a template for the method parameters, return value, etc.